# Mongodb $cond inside $cond

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have to apply group by operation on Campaign_Name and then sum aggregator on a field which will be decided based on some condition. I am facing some syntax error in the below code sample:

```
   $group : {
              _id: "$Campaign_Name",
              Basecount: {
                $sum: {
                  $cond: [
                    { "Recharge_Flag_Overall": { $eq: "NA"} },
                    $cond: [
                      { "Plus_Orn" : { $eq: 0} },
                      "$Winback_Orn",
                      "$Plus_Orn"
                    ],
                    "$Basecount"
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
```

Now, the condition for the sum aggregator is that if `Recharge_Flag_Overall` value is "NA", then I need to check the value of `Plus_Orn` and, if it is 1, then I have to take the sum of `Plus_Orn`, else the sum of the field named `Winback_Orn`. Otherwise, if the `Recharge_Flag_Overall` value is not "NA", then simply, I have to take the sum of a field named `Basecount`

> Note: `Plus_Orn` and `Winback_Orn` have only 0 or 1 as their values

Comment: Haven't got the time to test, but on first look, shouldn't wrapping the inner `$cond` in `{ ... }` be enough to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there, just have to correct the syntax of `$eq` operator,

```
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$Campaign_Name",
      Basecount: {
        $sum: {
          $cond: [
            { $eq: ["$Recharge_Flag_Overall", "NA"] },
            {
              $cond: [
                { $eq: ["$Plus_Orn", 0] },
                "$Winback_Orn",
                "$Plus_Orn"
              ]
            },
            "$Basecount"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
```